# My Path Animation Scene in Blender only renders the very first time

Tags: rendering, animation, keyframes

Okay, so my problem is that only the very first frame of my 720 frame animation is rendered.
Heres the file for you to check:

[image]

Comment: After changing the output path to something that exists on my drive, I was able to render the entire animation normally: https://imgur.com/a/od0nzDO

Comment: So maybe try with a different output path that is not in OneDrive or something.